# Relation between elliptic curve and Fermat's last thereom

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, abelian-varieties

I am looking for a elaborate explanation how the elliptic curve $E (a, b) := y^2=x(x-a)(x-b)$ is associated with the solution of $a^n+b^n=c^n$.

In 1969 Hellegouarch performed the elliptic curves $E (a, b)$, which were later named after Gerhard Frey and were constructed from the solutions of the Fermat equation, he reported on the curves in an article in Acta Arithmetica. I have found the [article](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa26/aa2636.pdf) but it is not in English.

Answer (score 4):

Alf van der Pooreten, Notes on Fermat's Last Theorem. Reviewed by Andrew Granville [here](https://dms.umontreal.ca/~andrew/PDF/VanderP.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

Takeshi Saito: Fermat's last theorem ([volume 1](https://www.ams.org/publications/authors/books/postpub/mmono-243) and [volume 2](https://www.ams.org/publications/authors/books/postpub/mmono-245)).

Answer (score 2):

> In 1969 Hellegouarch performed the elliptic curves $F (a, b)$, which were later named after Gerhard Frey and were constructed from the solutions of the Fermat equation, he reported on the curves in an article in Acta Arithmetica. I have found the [article](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa26/aa2636.pdf) but it is not in English.

Let me give you a over-simplified version taken form the lecture-series ["Riemann Hypothesis and its Applications" (Lecture-29)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nYfSo7Xq0Jc&t=325s) by Prof. Manindra Agrawal, Department of Computer Science and Engineering, IIT Kanpur (won the 2006 Fulkerson Prize, and the 2006 Gödel Prize for the AKS primality test).

**First Step**

Let $F:= y^2=x^3+ax^2+bx+c$, then discriminant $\Delta_F=(ab)^2+4a^3c-4b^3+18abc-27c^3.$

If $c=0$, then $y^2=x^3+ax^2+bx$, $\Delta_F=(ab)^2-4b^3.$

**Now the Frey's curve is** , $y^2=x(x-A)(x+B)=(x^2-Ax)(x+B)=x^3-Ax^2+Bx^2-ABx.$

Let, $a=(B-A), b=-AB,$ then $\Delta= \{(B-A)(-AB)\}^2-4(-AB)^3= \{(B-A)^2-4(-AB)\}(-AB)^2=(A^2+B^2-2AB+4Ab)(AB)^2=(A+B)^2(AB)^2.$

Now, let, $A=a^q, B=b^q,$ then, $\Delta_F=(a^q+b^q)^2(ab)^{2q},$

**if** $a^q+b^q=c^q$ **is true** for $q>2$ **(this is Fermat's last theorem)**,

then the discriminant $\Delta_F=(c^q)^2(ab)^{2q}=(abc)^{2q}.$

**Second Step**

If $\Delta_F$ is $l^{th}$ power of an integer, then it has a point of order $l$. **If** $a^q+b^q=c^q$ **is true for** $q>2$, then the Frey curve $F$ has a point a point of order $2q$, since it's discriminant $\Delta_F$ is $2q^{th}$ power of an integer $(abc)$.

**Third Step**

But if $F$ is modular, then, it does not have a point of order $ > C$ where $C$ is a constant.

**Fourth Step**

It has been proved that every elliptic curve is modular ([Taniyama–Shimura conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modularity_theorem), Andrew Wiles proved the Taniyama–Shimura conjecture for semistable elliptic curves, which was enough to imply Frey curve is modular).

**Final Step**

Since Frey curve $F$ is modular, then it can not have a point of order $ \geq C$, but the Frey curve $F$'s discriminant $\Delta_F$ is $2q^{th}$ power of an integer $(abc)$, so $q$ can not be $> \frac{C}{2}$, does there could not be solution $a^q+b^q=c^q$ for $q> \frac{C}{2}$, i.e. there are finite $q$ for which Fermat's Last Theorem is true.

*Frey's curve can not be constructed since by the definition of the Frey's Curve, it must have a point of order $2q$ but at the same time it is an elliptic curve, thus modular, so, the Frey's Curve can not have a point of order $ \geq C$, so after certain value of $q$, Frey's curve can not be constructed.*

Of-course I have missed many intricate details for the sake of accessibility.

**In a bit more technical terms:** The group of $p$-torsion points $F[p]$ on $F$
(which is a two-dimensional vector space over the field $\mathbb F_p$ of $p$-elements),

equipped with an action of the Galois group of $\overline{\mathbb Q}$ over $\mathbb Q$)  has very special properties,

in algebraic number theory terms, it is very close to being unramified, specifically, but more technically, it is unramified except possibly at $2$ and $p$, and at $p$ the ramification is very mild, it is finite flat.

Now the Shimura-Taniyama conjecture, which is what Wiles (together with Taylor)
proved, shows that $F$, and so $F[p]$, arises from a weight two modular form.  Ribet's earlier results on Serre's epsilon conjecture imply that this modular
form must actually be of level $2$. (This is where we use the above information about the ramification.)   But there are no non-zero cuspforms of weight $2$ and level $2$, and we get a contradiction.

Although it is much harder (in that the only way we know to rule out the existence of $F[p]$ is by the - quite difficult- Shimura-Taniyama
conjecture, or else by related more recent results such as Khare and Wintenberger's work on Serre's conjecture), one can think of the non-existence
of $F[p]$ as being analogous to Minkowski's theorem in algebraic number theory, which says that an everywhere-unramified extension of $\mathbb Q$ cannot exist (See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/177044/179940)).

**For detail proof, read following books:**

*1. Fermat's Last Theorem: Basic Tools by Takeshi Saito
(Publication Year: 2013),*

*2. Fermat's Last Theorem: The Proof by Takeshi Saito (Publication Year: 2014).*